# Publishing visual studio setup (installer project extension)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I created setup with Visual Studio 2015 installer project extension, but how do i publish it so i can install program on other computer?

Comment: If you created a setup with the installer extension, then either it's a ClickOnce per-user setup that you publish to a network or it's an MSI file based setup. You need to expand on which it is and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to distribute your Visual Studio extensions for project templates is via [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/).

As they mentioned [Publishing a Visual Studio Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728613.aspx) on official MSDN documentation walkthrough... so just follow steps that they are provided on MSDN.

1. Make sure that you have built the Release version of your extension and that it is up-to-date.
2. In a web browser, open the Visual Studio Gallery website.
3. In the upper-right corner, click SIGN IN.
4. Use your Microsoft account to sign in. If you do not have a Microsoft account, you can create one at this point.
5. Click **Upload**.
6. In **Step 1: Extension Type**, select **Tool** and then click **Next**.
7. In **Step 2: Upload**, you can choose to upload directly to Visual Studio Gallery or just add a link to your own website. In this case select **I would like to upload my tool**. The **Select your control** box appears. Click **Browse** and then select TestPublish.vsix in the \bin\Release folder of the project. Click **Next**.
8. In **Step 3: Basic Information**, fields from the source.extension.vsixmanifest file are displayed. Select an appropriate **Category** and add **Tags** to help users find your extension. You may want to add a more detailed summary and description (the description must be at least 280 characters long). Leave **Extension Type** as **Not a Microsoft Extension** and **Cost Category** as **Trial**.
9. Read the Contribution Agreement at the bottom of the page and check **I agree**.
10. Click **Create Contribution**. This displays the page your extension will have on the Visual Studio Gallery, with a message that the page has not yet been published.
11. Click **Publish**.
12. Search the Visual Studio Gallery for your extension. The listing for the TestPublish extension should appear.

For more information go to this **[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728613.aspx)**.

After you successfully upload your extension you will be able to install it and other user will be too... on Visual Studio Gallery extensions are globally available to install.

> Note: steps are copied from MSDN thread which URL is provided in this answer.